# User e-mail preferences don't update (immediately) after you save settings

Tags: support, profile-page, notifications, email

In the user e-mail preferences, I change my old e-mail address to my updated one. After I click "Save E-Mail Settings," I reload the page. The e-mail address changed back to what it was before I changed it. Is it impossible to change the e-mail address that you use to receive notifications and newsletters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that particular email address is used to notify you of things, we require that you verify it before it actually gets used. You should receive an email to that address shortly (if you haven't received it already) to verify it's a valid email address. Once you've clicked the link to verify, your email address in your preferences will update to your new one. Until then, it shows your old one where emails are still being sent.

This is rather confusing, and you're not the first who's been confused about it. [Hopefully we can do something about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246490/show-unconfirmed-email-addresses-in-the-preferences-tab) sooner rather than later.